# matlab histc with discontinuous intervals

Tags: matlab, histogram

I am stuck with this problem for the past few days! So, any help would be greatly appreciated.

THE PROBLEM:

---

I have a huge list of discontinuous intervals, about 80000 of them, spread over the range from 1 to 250 million. And I have a much larger set of numbers (a vector of about 200 million elements) spread over the same range, i.e., 1 to 250 million. As if this was not complex enough, some of these intervals may overlap, but most of them are expected to be discontinuous.

Now I want to do a histogram count of how many elements of the vector fall within each of the intervals. If these were simply continuous intervals (without gaps), then one could use histc. Even if the intervals were guaranteed to be always discontinuous (i.e., with gaps), I could have still used histc and thrown out the counts in the gaps. But since I do not have the guarantee that the intervals would always be discontinuous, I am stumped.

So far, I tried two ways of attacking this problem:

1) Simply loop through the intervals, and do sum(vector >= start & vector <= end) inside the for loop. This was hopelessly slow.

2) Use cellfun or arrayfun like this: cellfun(@(L,U) sum(histc(vector,[L U])), Strts, Ends); where Strts and Ends are cell arrays defining the intervals.

Although the second solution would take a few hours, since I need to do this operation for hundreds of large datasets, I cannot afford the time.

So, is there a better way?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Also answered here: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/110125#answer_118747

Answer (score 1):

How about `bsxfun`?

```
sum(bsxfun(@gt, vector(:), start(:).') & bsxfun(@le, vector(:), stop(:).'))
```

If you have memory limitations, you may have to work dividing `vector` in chunks and summing all partial results:

```
chunksize = 1e4; %// set as allowed by your memory
total = zeros(1,length(start)); %// initiallize
vector = vector(:); %// make column vector
for cut = 1:chunksize:length(vector)
    total = total + sum(bsxfun(@gt, vector(cut+(0:chunksize-1)), start(:).') & bsxfun(@le, vector(cut+(0:chunksize-1)), stop(:).'));
end
```

Comment: You should be partitioning start and end, since they have 1-250 million elements. This will also benefit performance.

Comment: This uses `chunksize * nintervals` memory.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have much more numbers than intervals, the best way would be to choose the fastest solution possible to process all the numbers, which is probably by using `histc` (which is written in C) and then do as much pre- and post-processing on the intervals and histogram counts as you like, since any time spent on these will anyhow be negligible.

My idea would be to put all the start and stop edges of the intervals together in one sorted vector `edges`, remove all duplicates, and then do a `histc` with those edges. To get the total counts per interval, you simply lookup the indices of both sides of the interval into the `edges` vector, and sum up all the individual bins that form the interval (since the original interval might be sliced up in several bins due to the overlapping). Something like this (untested):

```
edges = unique([start(:); stop(:)]); % should be sorted

counts = histc(data, edges); % should dominate running time

% find indices of start and stop vectors in edges,
% this should use binary search into sorted vectors, so reasonably fast
[~, istart] = ismember(start, edges);
[~, istop] = ismember(stop, edges);

interval_counts = arrayfun(@(low, hi) sum(counts(low:high-1)), istart, istop);
```

If the amount of numbers is too big to fit in memory (maybe you read them from file or so), it is straightforward to do the histogram calculation in chunks (pseudocode):

```
counts = 0;
while any_chunks_left()
    counts = counts + histc(get_chunk());
end
```

Assuming this works, this solution should use an amount of memory proportional to `max(chunksize, ninterval)`, which is much less than in Luis' and Oleg's solutions. I guess the total running time is only limited by the speed of `histc`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final take on this:

I tried using the bsxfun function, but because of the large sizes I am dealing with, I ran out of memory rather quickly.

So, the simplest possible technique that actually worked was:

```
BINVec = zeros(1,Siz_Including_All_Intvls,'uint8'); 
BINVec(vector) = 1; 
SumVec = cellfun(@(L,U) sum(BINVec(L:U)), strts, ends);
```

where strts and ends define the intervals in cell arrays.

This code was very fast and I had the results in a few minutes for all the datasets I wanted to process! Lesson I learnt: Sometimes, the most underestimated solution is the one that works best. Although the above struck me earlier, I simply dismissed the thought assuming this would be very slow.

I did learn about the use of bsxfun from your answers and I personally also like Bas's solution!  Will remember that for the future!

As far as this instance is concerned, I solved it using the above.

Thanks a lot for your inputs!

Happy Holidays!